# OpenCV cvRemap Cropping Image

Tags: opencv, crop, distortion

So I am very new to OpenCV (2.1), so please keep that in mind.

So I managed to calibrate my cheap web camera that I am using (with a **wide angle** attachment), using the checkerboard calibration method to produce the intrinsic and distortion coefficients.

I then have no trouble feeding these values back in and producing image maps, which I then apply to a video feed to correct the incoming images.

I run into an issue however. I know when it is warping/correcting the image, it creates several skewed sections, and then formats the image to crop out any black areas. My question then is can I view the complete warped image, including some regions that have black areas? Below is an example of the black regions with skewed sections I was trying to convey if my terminology was off:

An image better conveying the regions I am talking about can be [found here](http://photo.net/learn/fisheye/fe06.jpg)! This image was discovered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477774/correcting-fisheye-distortion-programmatically).

**Currently:** The cvRemap() returns basically the yellow box in the image linked above, but I want to see the whole image as there is relevant data I am looking to get out of it.

**What I've tried:**  Applying a scale conversion to the image map to fit the complete image (including stretched parts) into frame

```
        CvMat *intrinsic = (CvMat*)cvLoad( "Intrinsics.xml" );
        CvMat *distortion = (CvMat*)cvLoad( "Distortion.xml" );

        cvInitUndistortMap( intrinsic, distortion, mapx, mapy );

        cvConvertScale(mapx, mapx, 1.25, -shift_x);   // Some sort of scale conversion
        cvConvertScale(mapy, mapy, 1.25, -shift_y);   // applied to the image map

        cvRemap(distorted,undistorted,mapx,mapy);
```

The cvConvertScale, when I think I have aligned the x/y shift correctly (guess/checking), is somehow distorting the image map making the correction useless. There might be some math involved here I am not correctly following/understanding.

Does anyone have any other suggestions to solve this problem, or what I might be doing wrong? I've also tried trying to write my own code to fix distortion issues, but lets just say OpenCV knows already how to do it well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From memory, you need to use [`InitUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix,distCoeffs,R,newCameraMatrix,map1,map2)`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#initundistortrectifymap), of which `InitUndistortMap` is a simplified version.

```
cvInitUndistortMap( intrinsic, distort, map1, map2 )
```

is equivalent to:

```
cvInitUndistortRectifyMap( intrinsic, distort, Identity matrix, intrinsic, 
                           map1, map2 )
```

The new parameters are `R` and `newCameraMatrix`. `R` species an additional transformation (e.g. rotation) to perform (just set it to the identity matrix).

The parameter of interest to you is `newCameraMatrix`. In `InitUndistortMap` this is the same as the original camera matrix, but you can use it to get that scaling effect you're talking about.

You get the new camera matrix with [`GetOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMat, distCoeffs, imageSize, alpha,...)`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#getoptimalnewcameramatrix). You basically feed in `intrinsic`, `distort`, your original image size, and a parameter `alpha` (along with containers to hold the result matrix, see documentation). The parameter `alpha` will achieve what you want.

I quote from the documentation:

> The function computes the optimal new camera matrix based on the free
>   scaling parameter. By varying this parameter the user may retrieve
>   **only sensible pixels alpha=0**, **keep all the original image pixels if
>   there is valuable information in the corners alpha=1**, or get something
>   in between. When alpha>0, the undistortion result will likely have
>   some black pixels corresponding to “virtual” pixels outside of the
>   captured distorted image. The original camera matrix, distortion
>   coefficients, the computed new camera matrix and the newImageSize
>   should be passed to InitUndistortRectifyMap to produce the maps for
>   Remap.

So for the extreme example with all the black bits showing you want `alpha=1`.

In summary:

- call `cvGetOptimalNewCameraMatrix` with `alpha=1` to obtain `newCameraMatrix`.
- use `cvInitUndistortRectifymap` with `R` being identity matrix and `newCameraMatrix` set to the one you just calculated
- feed the new maps into `cvRemap`.

Comment: mathematical.coffee, I cannot thank you enough. This was exactly what I was looking for and with your detailed solution, I was able to implement it accordingly! Thank you so much!

Comment: no worries :) it took me forever to work it out too (I find the online documentation a bit hard to understand sometimes, especially as I use the python interface). One invaluable resource (I find) are the examples included with OpenCV (in `OpenCV-2.x.x/samples/pick_your_language`).

Comment: But rectifitied image still have black area or borders .