# Improve cvFindChessboardCorners

Tags: opencv, detection, feature-detection, camera-calibration, distortion

Unfortunately, I was not able to find any solution to my question.

What I'm trying to do is to improve the results using the OpenCV-method `cvFindChessboardCorners` in order to be able to achieve a better camera calibration, because I think that this is the reason why I get poor results undistorting/rectifying images like in my question before ([Question: Undistorting/rectify images with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517989/undistorting-rectify-images-with-opencv)).

So, what I want to know is, how I can improve the algorithm in order to be able to detect the chessboard corners in all images of this link: 
http://abload.de/img/cvfindchessboardcorneoxs73.jpg

Everything works fine, only in the two last images the chessboard could not be detected.
Any help or advice or hint is very welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide the original, unprocessed (problematic) single images in full resolution?

Comment: I got them from here: https://sites.google.com/site/scarabotix/ocamcalib-toolbox/ocamcalib-toolbox-download-page, you can download them at the bottom of that page, the filename is sampleimages.zip

Comment: ok... some single corners/squares aren't extracted by opencv's findChessboardCorners method (1 missing corner in the last image and 2 in the second last image). Computing a gradient magnitude image, the corners look 'ok', so maybe you can improve the result. I guess corners aren't extracted because there is too much white in some of the black squares from the light (so a thresholding problem). I'll try an approach: finding contours with gradient magnitude, then enhance the black squares by drawing filled contour.

Comment: Thanks very much! Now I'm trying to get to run the OpenCV sample-file "edge.cpp", but I somehow do not get it to work. I will keep you updatet on my progress

Comment: Unfortunately, calculating the edge map of the images did not help me to improve the results of cvFindChessboardCorners.

Comment: didn't find an easy solution either... sorry

Comment: No need to be sorry. I tried interpolating the given coordinates in order to calculate the intersection of the polynomials which I hoped would be the missing corner, but it did not work out too well... I also posed another question dealing with that. Thanks anyway :)