# Not finding all inner corners of a chessboard

Tags: opencv, chess, camera-calibration

I already had two questions on here ([Undistorting/rectify images with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517989/undistorting-rectify-images-with-opencv) and [Improve cvFindChessboardCorners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428124/improve-cvfindchessboardcorners?lq=1)) which led me to the cause of my problem.

So, as you can see in this picture (http://abload.de/img/cvfindchessboardcornet9pn4.jpg) all inner corners of this chessboard are found except the ones in the upper left area.
For the second image, I tried interpolating the coordinates of found corners both in vertical and horizontal direction in order to calculate their intersection, but I couldn't locate the corner that way (the x-coordinate was correct, but the y-coordinate wasn't due to the curvature of the interpolating polnomials).

**Problem:** The trouble is, that interpolation won't work in the first picture, because there is no such polynomial, at least for the interpolation in vertical direction (because that would be in conflict with the fundamental definition of a mathematical function.

So, I'm really clueless, how to extract the remaining coordinates of the corners which cannot be found by cvFindChessboardCorners

Comment: Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this? How can I find those inner coners of the chessboard in the upper left-hand corner?

Comment: The OpenCV findChessboardCorners() algorithm is not very good. While I find it inspiring to read http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.5491.pdf, I think that the ultimate algorithm is still the one by Andreas Geiger: http://cvlibs.net/software/libcbdetect

Comment: After trying many existing algorithms it seems that libcbdetect stands the top in terms of accuracy, while OpenCV is a compromise between speed and accuracy - findChessboardCorners can run at 40fps@720p but libcbdetect takes ~1s on each 720p image.