# Projection of circular region of interest onto rectangle

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to take a circular region of interest from a rectangular image and project it onto a rectangle. This is illustrated in the following image:

[image]

I want to accomplish this, preferably using MATLAB, but even the general concept of how it can be done using any other language would suffice.

Thank you!

Comment: This is very similar to taking a fisheye lens image and undistorting it so that it maps to a rectangular plane.  See this post for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477774/correcting-fisheye-distortion-programmatically

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess, I was just not searching with the right keywords :)

Comment: No problem at all :)  However, if you don't know the camera parameters of whatever device took that image, it's going to be a bit difficult to fully undistort the image properly.  You'll have to play around with the parameters or do trial and error to get it working properly.  Good luck!