# C# Flatten fisheye into rectangle for AI

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, computer-vision, fisheye

I have a camera from which I pull images I want to give to an AI model on Azure. The camera has a fisheye lens and the output looks like this (OpenLab at TUKE University if you are interested):

[image]

I want to flatten it into rectangle to increase accuracy. I have already read this question where there was a similar problem: [Circular Fisheye Image dewarp to flat image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560580/circular-fisheye-image-dewarp-to-flat-image) but it is quite old and did not help much. I think OpenCVSharp would be the right thing to use but feel free to suggest any other tool/library/algorithm that could be used for this.

Comment: OpenCV seem to be the go-to way to do things like this. I have used the emguCV wrapper, but OpenCVSharp should be equivalent. See [Fisheye methods](https://emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/3e001d89-862e-16a1-e621-9cdfb0a3c4b9.htm)

Comment: @JonasH Hopefully someone will post an example, because I do not like my chances doing this on my own

Comment: I have not done fisheye compensation, but I have done some camera calibration, and it seem to be very similar concept. [The are some guides on how to do it in c++ that might be helpful](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html)